# Concatenate hive analog in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have a spark job which create a one result table in Hive and load data from the other tables.
This job is executed every day and generates a lot of file on HDFS. 
When I used Hive I make a script: alter table quality_of_service_1 concatenate;

```
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .appName("Test")
    .getOrCreate()


  def build(implicit session: SparkSession, config: Config): Unit = {
    import session.implicits._
    loadData
      .flatMap(Item.buildInternal(_, config))
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .format("orc")
      .saveAsTable(s"${config.schema}.result_table")
  }
```

Could you please write how to merge this files and where it tunes? Shell script with HDFS, spark or spark session configs.

Config:

```
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.rpc.message.maxSize=300 \
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=1009 \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1009 \
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=31457280 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1200 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=400 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1200 \
--conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=1073741824 \
--executor-cores 3 \
--executor-memory 7g \
--driver-memory 4g \
```

Comment: Why do you need 4g for the driver? And why are your initial executors equal to the max?

Comment: How much g do I need for the driver and initial executors? I tried to increase to 7g and maxExecutors=1500, but got the same result.

Comment: The driver isn't going to do much work. You can start it with 1g. And initial executors, maybe 600-800 based on your current min and max

Comment: Changed the config but size of result files is from 3,5 to 6,5 mb and quantity more than 6500, but I need less than 1000.

Comment: Have you tried less executors? Used coalesce function?

Comment: Sure, coalesce dont help.

Comment: Why not? The point of that function is to reduce the number of executors, thus combining the created partitions , and therefore making fewer processes managing the same data. When written out, there are fewer, larger files

Answer (score 0):

In spark2, a parameter controls the size of one partition ... thus the number of files when you "save".
So increase the parameter to have less partitions and after less files
For example, a one gigabyte per partition
`val maxSplit=1024*1024*1024
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes", maxSplit)`

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tried to use this config in .sh file but got near 6000 files of 4.5 mb. But after executed   alter table result_table concatenate I got near 150 files of 450 mb.
The spark-sql_2.11 version is 2.0.2. Could you please write I did wrong? Updated the question with full config.

Comment: @Vad what  size are you expecting?

Comment: From 200 to 1000mb.